# TypeError: reaction.fetchMembers is not a function

Tags: bots, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to get the list of users who reacted to a message at a specific time, this is my code and the error

```
c.messages.fetch(msgId).then(async themessage => {
    for (const reaction of themessage.reactions.cache)
    {
         for (let user of await reaction.fetchMembers())
         {
             console.log(user);
         }
         console.log(reaction);
    }
});
```

The error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: reaction.fetchMembers is not a function
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I migrate my code to Discord.js v12 from v11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63911361/how-can-i-migrate-my-code-to-discord-js-v12-from-v11)

Answer (score 0):

`reaction` is defined as a collection from `themessage.reactions.cache` so you can not use any method that is not listed in the [`Collection` class on the docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection).

Your solution is:

Replacing `await reaction.fetchMembers()` with `reaction.users.cache.array()`.

And by also replacing `themessage.reactions.cache` with `themessage.reactions.cache.array()`

Comment: The error has changed, now it is `TypeError: Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined`

And when using `console.log(reaction.users.cache)` to check its value, it returns `undefined`

Comment: Now
`for (let user of reaction.users.cache.array())
{
    console.log(user);
}` 
Won't log anything. Checking the length of `reaction.users.cache.array()` returns 0.

Comment: try logging `themessage.reactions.cache.array()`

Comment: it returns an output that is too long for a comment. is there another way of sending it to you?

Comment: You can upload it to hastebin or pastebin

Comment: Ok, here you go: pastebin.com/u8avt3KR